# Entity Framework 1-n

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Não sei nem se tem sentido o que estou querendo fazer.

Se tento adicionar um Curso em uma Bandeira, tudo bem. Porém quando tento adicionar uma lista de Cursos em uma Bandeira, acontece o seguinte erro:

> Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by
>   multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

Classes:

```
[Table("Area_Cursos_Bandeira")]
public class Bandeira
{
    public int BandeiraID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }
    public string Site { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Curso> Cursos { get; set; }
}

[Table("Area_Cursos_Curso")]
public class Curso
{
    public int CursoID { get; set; }
    public int BandeiraID { get; set; }
    public virtual Bandeira Bandeira { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Repositorio

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    return ctx.Set<TEntity>();
}

public void SalvarTodos()
{
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}

public void Adicionar(TEntity obj)
{
    ctx.Set<TEntity>().Add(obj);
}
```

Main

```
BancoContexto bc = new BancoContexto();
var bdBandeira = BandeiraAplicacaoConstrutor.BandeiraAplicacaoEF(bc);
var bdCurso = CursoAplicacaoConstrutor.CursoAplicacaoEF(bc);       
var todosCursos = bdCurso.GetAll().ToList();

var bandeiraADD = new Bandeira
{
    Logo = "logo",
    Nome = "nome",
    Site = "www.sdadas.com.bg",
    Cursos = todosCursos
 };

bdBandeira.Adicionar(bandeiraADD);
bdBandeira.SalvarTodos();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está carregando Bandeiras e Cursos em contextos diferentes. Pra que isso funcione, o contexto de Bandeiras e Cursos **precisa** ser o mesmo.

Eu faria algo assim:

```
var bdBandeira = BandeiraAplicacaoConstrutor.BandeiraAplicacaoEF(context);
var bdCurso = CursoAplicacaoConstrutor.CursoAplicacaoEF(context);
```

Comment: Mas como eu poderia passar o contexto? Pois o "main", não tem conhecimento do contexto.

Comment: Você teria que instanciar o contexto no Main.

Comment: Deu certo. Porém agora pelo que percebi, não existe mais sentido eu ter minha camada de aplicação, pois estou instanciando o contexto. Certo?

Comment: Certo. Na verdade eu estava tentando te explicar isso faz algum tempo ;)

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA. Agora faz sentido! Obg.

Comment: @DiegoZanardo A resposta resolveu o problema? Se sim, poderia marcar ela para sua pergunta ficar mais "bonitinha" (com um verdinho bonito). Se ainda falta algo, diga que tenho certeza que será respondido.